# Class Library (Legacy Portable)?

Tags: visual-studio, portable-class-library

I have one PC with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Version 15.2 and it has a project template for Class Library (Portable).

Another PC with Version 15.3.1 has a template for Class Library (Legacy Portable).  Are PCLs now legacy ?

Any current news on what I should be using instead ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, "should", I won't say that without seeing **exactly** what you're doing but yes, PCLs are now "legacy", the new way is .NET Standard and .NET Core.

Please note that legacy does not mean "will stop working" so there shouldn't be a need to *do* anything as of yet.

To figure out which kind of .NET Standard version you want to target to get-out-of-legacy, you can consult the compatibility list on the [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#pcl-compatibility) web page.

Specifically, you likely want to consult the other matrix on the same web page, the [.NET Implementation Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) matrix and figure out which platforms you want to target, then create a "Class Library (.NET Standard)" project targetting the highest .NET Standard version you can get away with.

Comment: I might be missing the context, but: " targetting the **highest** .NET Standard version you can get away with"? I guess you mean **lowest**, or?

Comment: No, I meant highest. the higher the .net standard, the fewer platforms and runtimes will it be compatible with, but the more api's you have access to. In other words, find which platforms you must target and pick the highest standard version that will support them all, that will give you the most apis available for your project.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean now. Thanks!